# Create a donwloadable content Apps with Javascript and HTML5 for Mobile Devices

Tags: javascript, android, ios, html

Hello Everyone and thanks for taking the time to answer my question!

**I want to create a simple app to display up to date information to our client. The App should check the latest "data" on the server every time the aplication start and download it to the client. That way the app will be able to use that "data" to show the information.**

Does anyone know how I can do that with only JavaScript or maybe a JSON file and HTML5, or do you have any suggestion the best way to do something like that?

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 1):

You can generate JSON on yor server and parse that on the mobile device to display the data.

**It's generally better to use native code instead of wrapping a HTML Application into your Android App. That way you can also use [Google Material Design](https://www.google.com/design/spec/material-design/introduction.html).**

Comment: Thank you very much for your suggestion, looks like JSON technique its a simple way, by the way our client still want the apps to build with HTML5 ^_^, but thanks again for helping

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you don't want to write a separate native app for both Android and IOS, you could create a single mobile application using PhoneGap that is just a single HTML page with Javascript that does an XHR call to your server when it loads and stores the response JSON locally. PhoneGap allows you to compile versions for IOS and Android from a single codebase.

With PhoneGap there is a handler that gets called when the app loads that you can use:

```
function onDeviceReady() {
    $.getJSON("http://yourserver/yourfile.json", function( data ) {
      //do whatever you want with the data to store it
    })
}
```

Comment: thank you very much @mcgraphix, i will try the code in my apps and store the json locally, thanks again for helping me